# Xcode Shared Framework Linking Issue In Multi-Target Project

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, frameworks

We have an Xcode project with many app targets, e.g.:

- Target `A` depends on the shared framework `Airship`
- Target `B` does not depend on any framework

The problem is that when I compile `A` first the Airship framework is is already copied/built into the derived data folder and also in the app `A`.

When I then compile `B` (Xcode chooses the same derived data folder) Xcode writes this framework for whatever reason in the linked frameworks of the binary. `otool -L` result:

```
@rpath/Airship.framework/Airship (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
```

At the same time Airship is not copied to the app package's Frameworks directory since we don't reference it in that target. **Of course the app crashes on run...**

Is this maybe a known Xcode bug? Xcode should not reference frameworks **not linked** to a target inside the resulting binary...

I already tried to reference the framework as optional in **every** app target which builds and does not crash  **but** when I submit this to the App Store I get the warning from the screenshot below...

[image: from this screenhot]